# Replace list object based on indexes of another list (Python)

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm writing a program that plays hangman with the user. At the moment, it has two lists: one list that contains a mutable version of the word, and the other the 'status' of the user's guesses. So if the word was "python":

```
word = ["p", "y", "t", "h", "o", "n"]

status = []
for number in range(0, len(word)):
    status.append("_")

print(status)
>>> ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
```

My plan is that after each `input("Enter guess: ")` I can replace the "_" with the guess, according to the index that the guess has in the 'word' list. (does that make sense?!)

Then, after each guess, I can `print("".join(status))` so the user can see how they are going.

I did some research and came across the method `list.index(x)`, but I read that it returns the index of the first item whose value is x.

Here is an example of how I want the program to work:

```
word = ["p", "y", "t", "h", "o", "n"]
status = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]

Enter guess: t
_ _ t _ _ _

Enter guess: n
_ _ t _ _ n
```

etc. etc. (don't worry about the loop etc. cause I have that down :) I'm just not sure how I can edit one list based on the indexes of another!)

I wasn't planning to modify 'word', so that in the end I could compare 'status' and 'word' to check if the user has won, but I would be open to all suggestions!! :D

Thanks!!

Comment: "I [..] came across the method list.index(x), but I read that it returns the index of the first item whose value is x." - that's just what you need. you can make a loop to find all the occurences. show us you code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all of the indices whose value is `x` using a list comprehension:

```
indices = [i for i, elem in enumerate(word) if elem == x]
```

So you would have:

```
>>> word = ["p", "y", "t", "h", "o", "n"]
status = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
>>> >>> word
['p', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
>>> status
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

Then, the user makes a guess, say we have `guess = 't'`, then:

```
>>> guess = 't'
>>> indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(word) if x == guess]
>>> indices
[2]
```

Then we mutate the status list to show the indices that were found:

```
for i in indices:
    status[i] = guess
```

We can then display `status` as a string:

```
print(' '.join(status))
_ _ t _ _ _
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks. I've always had trouble with list comprehensions... but then again I've only spent 5 wks with Python :)

Answer (score 0):

This ought to work:

```
word = ['p','y','t','h','o','n']
user_letter = raw_input("Enter a letter\n")

status = ['_' for i in xrange(len(word))]
for index, ltr in enumerate(word):
     if ltr == user_letter:
         status[index] = user_letter
```

This assumes that the `user_letter` is of length 1. Of course, that is something you can ensure for yourself.